# Selecting specific columns and adding csv names to final csv file

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to extract the same first 16 columns of data from many csv files that are in different sub-directories and add the csv file names to each row of the final csv. My code:

```
getwd()
root<-list.dirs(".", recursive=TRUE)
# get list of files ending in csv in directory root
dir(root, pattern='csv$', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) %>%
# read files into data frames
lapply(FUN = read.csv) %>%
# bind all data frames into a single data frame
rbind_all %>%
# write into a single csv file
write.csv("all.csv")
```

I'd like to know where to put the select columns and add file names code.

ANSWER:

```
getwd()
root<-list.dirs(".", recursive=TRUE)
# get list of files ending in csv in directory root
dir(root, pattern='csv$', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) %>%
# read files into data frames, select first 16 columns and add filename 
lapply(FUN = function(p) read.csv(p) %>% select(1:16) %>%    

mutate(file_name=p)) %>%     
# bind all data frames into a single data frame
rbind_all %>%
# write into a single csv file
write.csv("all.csv")
```

Comment: I would do it at the `lapply` step, that's the last time you can access file name/path. maybe something like this : `lapply(FUN = function(p) read.csv(p) %>% select(1:16) %>% mutate(file_name=p)) %>%`

Comment: Thank you scoa! I modified with answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it at the time where you use lapply, since this is the last step where you can access file name/path:

```
dir(root, pattern='csv$', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) %>%
  lapply(FUN = function(p) read.csv(p) %>% select(1:16) %>% mutate(file_name=p)) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  write.csv("all.csv")
```

Comment: Use `bind_rows` instead of `rbind_all`, see this http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/dplyr/man/bind.html